# Install apps to SD card in android 4.4.2

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, external-sd

I made the sd card as the default install location in my phone settings but this didn't take effect, then i run adb commands to force the phone to have default install location as external using these 2 commands:

> adb shell pm set-install-location 2
>
> adb shell pm get-install-location

The output says 2[external] but i verified by installing new apps they get directly to insternal storage.

I was hoping to take advantage of this method to make possible apps can write in sd card bypassing android limitation. So do you know why this commands didn't affect the system ? is there  an equivalent command to do this ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Some apps, stated in their manifest files, cannot be installed to external storage (SD card). That setting will not affect those apps. You should try some other apps for verification.